# Oracle Database Migration using Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer, migration

I've 2 Oracle database on different machines [I connect to them via oracle SQL Developer
[image]

Now I am planning to have machine 3 which will consolidate both Oracle instances on one new node

[image]

Question is what is best way to do this ?

I surfed & found that oracle SQL Developer can help [check this Link](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldev/r31/DatabaseCopy/DatabaseCopy.html)

Does this will work ??
Or 
I have to fallow RMAN cloning option ?

What is best suitable way for doing this ?

Comment: I wouldn't use our Database Copy for this - that's more for ad hoc copies. If you want to migrate/consolidate entire instances, there are much more efficient ways.

Comment: `expdp` and `impdp` are probably a lot more efficient than using SQL Developer for this. If you can create a DBLink you don't even need intermediate files for that

Comment: Yep!! I am thinking exdp & impdp too. I am exploring all possible ways as db is not live & I am just running tests. @a_horse_with_no_name : I used DB links for vertical & horizontal fragmentation, who it can help in migrations ?

Answer (score 1):

why do you need windows at all? you even do not need sql developer.

- shutdown the source database
- scp datafiles(.dbf .ctl)
- scp files in ORACLE_HOME/dbs (like initSID.ora, spfileSID.ora, and also password file)
- you should also create dirs for diagnostic_dest (where alert.log is placed)
- amend `/etc/oratab`
- set the right SID
- start the database

PS: this assumes that the Oracle version (including fixpack) is exactly the same.

Comment: Let me try this!!,  Any URL where i can get this [I am linux developer, little DBA migration skills]

Comment: I was even thinking of DataPump

Answer (score 1):

As time goes on, this answer changes.

Current answer should involve a move to a Multi-Tenant setup.  The latest version (19c, soon 20c) allows 3 Plugable Databases (PDB) without a license.

[Licensing Information for 19c:](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dblic/Licensing-Information.html#GUID-0F9EB85D-4610-4EDF-89C2-4916A0E7AC87)

> For all offerings, if you are not licensed for Oracle Multitenant, then you may have up to 3 user-created PDBs in a given container database at any time.